# Permissions error using deploy-cloud-functions GitHub Action

Tags: google-cloud-functions, github-actions, google-cloud-iam

I'm using [deploy-cloud-functions](https://github.com/google-github-actions/deploy-cloud-functions) GitHub Action to deploy a Cloud Function. I've successfully deployed one Cloud Function using it but a second one (using the same service account, in the same project, using the same workflow) is producing an error:

```
Run google-github-actions/deploy-cloud-functions@v0
Extracted project ID 'my-project' from $GCLOUD_PROJECT
Created zip file from './' at '/tmp/cfsrc-50378e4a065cfb06ed27a123.zip'
Error: google-github-actions/deploy-cloud-functions failed with: failed to upload zip file: The caller does not have permission
```

To confirm, all services have been enabled and I have created a new service account and assigned it both the `iam.serviceAccountUser` role and the `iam.cloudFunctionsDeveloper` role on the project -- in line with the [authorization guidelines](https://github.com/google-github-actions/deploy-cloud-functions#authorization).

I've also setup Workload Identity Federation and am using that for authentication between GitHub and GCP.

Creating a pool:

```
gcloud iam workload-identity-pools create github-pool \
    --location="global" \
    --display-name="GitHub pool"
```

And a provider:

```
gcloud iam workload-identity-pools providers create-oidc github-provider \
    --location='global' \
    --workload-identity-pool=github-pool \
    --display-name='GitHub provider' \
    --attribute-mapping='google.subject=assertion.sub,attribute.actor=assertion.actor,attribute.repository=assertion.repository' \
    --issuer-uri='https://token.actions.githubusercontent.com'
```

And allowed impersonation of the service account:

```
gcloud iam service-accounts add-iam-policy-binding \
    github-actions-sa@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com \
    --role="roles/iam.workloadIdentityUser" \
    --member="principalSet://iam.googleapis.com/projects/1234567891234/locations/global/workloadIdentityPools/github-pool/attribute.repository/my-org/my-repo"
```

The GitHub Actions workflow I'm using is:

```yaml
name: CD

on:
  push:
    branches: [main]

  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    permissions:
      contents: "read"
      id-token: "write"

    steps:
      - name: "Checkout repository"
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - id: "auth"
        name: "Authenticate to Google Cloud"
        uses: "google-github-actions/auth@v0"
        with:
          workload_identity_provider: "projects/1234567891234/locations/global/workloadIdentityPools/github-pool"
          service_account: "github-actions-sa@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com"

      - id: "deploy"
        uses: "google-github-actions/deploy-cloud-functions@v0"
        with:
          name: "my-function"
          runtime: "python310"
          entry_point: "main"
          region: "europe-west6"
          service_account_email: github-actions-sa@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

I can't figure out why this function with the same service account in the same project is failing with a permissions error whilst another function works using the same setup.

**Can anyone suggest how I may resolve the permissions issue?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was due to my `--attribute-mapping` when creating the provider. In my case I wanted to deploy from ***multiple GitHub repositories (under one organization)*** using a single GitHub provider. By mapping the following attributes I limited access to only my personal GitHub account and one particular repository:

- `attribute.actor=assertion.actor` - The personal GitHub account that initiated the workflow
- `attribute.repository=assertion.repository` - The repository from where the workflow is running.

I recreated the provider using `repository_owner` instead:

```
--attribute-mapping="google.subject=assertion.sub,attribute.repository_owner=assertion.repository_owner"
```

- `repository_owner` - The name of the organization in which the repository is stored.

You need to wait up to 5 minutes for the permissions to update. After that my Cloud Function was successfully deployed.

The available claims on the GitHub OIDC token are [listed here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/deployment/security-hardening-your-deployments/about-security-hardening-with-openid-connect#understanding-the-oidc-token).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I spent more than a day dealing with it.
My solution was to provide **project_id** in the deploy step.
Otherwise, the impersonate-url was wrong.